# vba textbox clearing and if statments

Tags: excel, vba

I dont know why this if is not working i m getting values from 1 st if statment
for example: i want in textbox value from cell C3 instead im getting value from C2 it looks like this if don't woriking properly

```
 Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim tadeusz As String
Dim tadeuszilosc As String
Dim tadeuszdni As String
tadeusz = Range("A2")
tadeuszilosc = Range("C2")
tadeuszdni = Range("D2")

Dim kordian As String
Dim kordianilosc As String
Dim kordiandni As String

kordian = Range("A3")
kordianilosc = Range("B3")
kordiandni = Range("C3")

If (tadeusz = "Pan Tadeusz") Then
TextBox2.Value = Range("C2").Value
TextBox7.Value = Range("D2").Value
TextBox8.Value = Range("E2").Value
ElseIf (kordian = "Kordian") Then
TextBox2.Value = Range("C3").Value
TextBox7.Value = Range("D3").Value
TextBox8.Value = Range("E3").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If `A2` says "Pan Tadeusz" then `TextBox2` will hold the value in `C2`, if it doesn't then it will check if `A3` says "Kordian".  If it does then`TextBox2` will get the value in `C3`.  How is it not working properly?

Comment: You're checking values from two different cells, so the if/elseif seems a little odd here: what if both tests are true?